# How does polarity of a solvent increase conductance of electrolyte?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

My textbook says that electrolyte ionize more in polar solvents and greater is the polarity, larger is the conductance. But if polar solvents (lets take water) causes the formation of shells around electrolyte (say NaCl) then shouldn't effective size increase and hence conductance should decrease? What factor is more dominant? Size/Solvation or Polarity?

Comment: Gist - To have a current in solutions you need ions. Non-polar solvents don't dissolve ionic salts very well.

Comment: What about the viscosity?

Comment: @MaxW I understand that well but my question was that if polar solvents create shells around the ion shouldn't that inturn hinder the conductance of the electrolyte?

Comment: I wondered whether it could be about solubility or dissociation. Could NaCl be only partly dissociated in some solvents? Then again, as a wild guess, it seems like a polar solvent might become oriented to some degree with an electric field, extending the effect of that field over a greater distance, vaguely analogously to temporary magnetism.

Answer (score 2):

The important parameter is the dielectric constant (relative permitivitty) $\epsilon$ of the solvent because this controls the interaction energy $E$ between two ions at a fixed distance $r$ apart, i.e. $\displaystyle E\sim \frac{1}{\epsilon r}$. If the dielectric constant is large, for water it is 78 but for benzene 2.3 you can see that the interaction energy for benzene will be far larger than for water. This means that any pair of ions formed in benzene will be attracted to one another from a far greater distance (with the same energy) than the same ions in water would be. The chance that the ions separate is given relative to the thermal energy of the solvent which is just $RT$, so if the interaction energy is far larger than $RT$ the chance of separating is small and the ion does not dissolve and vice versa. The thermal energy of the solvent tries to jostle the ions apart.

Notes. The interaction energy is  $\displaystyle E(r,\epsilon)= \frac{Z_1Z_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{\epsilon r}$ where $Z$ are the charges, $e$ the charge on the electron and $\epsilon_0$ the permitivitty of free space.  The thermal energy per molecule at temperature $T$ is $k_BT$ where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and is $RT$ per mole. The probability of being at separation $r$ with dielectric constant $\epsilon$ is $\sim\exp(-E(r,\epsilon)/k_BT)$.

Comment: I would be really interested to know if there's a connection between polarity and the dielectric constant, and, without that, this doesn't seem to answer the original question. Are you saying that a polar solvent is not more likely to conduct more?

Comment: A polar solvent will conduct more because more ions will dissolve in it compared to a non-polar solvent. Think of the solubility of sodium chloride in water vs that in oil.  The dielectric constant is proportional to the polarisability of  the molecule (this measures how easily a dipole is *induced* in a molecule by an external electric field) and additionally by the square of the permanent dipole moment in a polar molecule.

Answer (score 0):

> My textbook says that electrolyte ionize more in polar solvents and greater is the polarity, larger is the conductance.

Porphyrin has already given a very useful explanation. I feel this the textbook sentence is quite problematic if taken literally. First of all, polarity is a useless term, it is an umbrella word which is discouraged by the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry. Dielectric constant is the right parameter in this context.

The first requirement of ionization in a solvent is indeed *solubility*. An ionic compound which is dissolved in a solvent will indeed generate ions whether it water or any other solvent. Salt won't dissolve in benzene so there is no change in the conductivity of the solvent. Let us take an example of HCl gas which is not ionic in nature-it is dipolar (i.e. it has a dipole moment). It is soluble in water (large dielectric) and benzene (low dielectric). When HCl dissolves in water it gives highly conducting solution because it can ionize there and when it dissolves in benzene it remains as HCl molecules. It cannot protonate benzene.

Now what you are thinking about it polar solvents forming a shell around an ion. Right, that is a different concept. Read about *transport numbers* of various ions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_transport_number.